# American communities vs communities in America

Tags: phrases, expressions, terminology

Is there a difference in meaning between:

1. "Helping migrants became part our communities in America."
   vs
2. "Helping migrants become part of our American communities."

It feels like option 1 is more inclusive, so they can join many communities, sporting, cultural etc. Whereas option 2 is more about having migrants integrate into our way of life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, *American communities* could be interpreted as groups of Americans living together in other countries, whereas *communities in America* doesn't have that ambiguity.